# Are you ever able to make new ramps to the beach?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've started up a new game of *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* and I'm trying to decide on a layout for my new town with Rover on the train. I'm trying to take future buildings and such into account in my decision in order to optimize my layout.

While I know that you can eventually build more bridges in the town, I'm wondering if you're ever able to build more ramps to the beach. I see that you start out with only 2, and on one of the maps I'm looking at as a potential choice, they're quite far away from each other.

Is this ever offered as a town improvement or is this one of the things that is an inherent quality of the map that you can't change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Prima Guide for the game, while you can build more bridges for the town, there isn't a public work that allows for more beach ramps.